# Casting numpy longdouble to mpmath.mpf

Tags: python, numpy, mpmath

How can I cast np.longdouble to mpmath.mpf?

```
import numpy as np
import mpmath

b = np.longdouble(1.0)
a = mpmath.mpf(b)
print (a)
```

Comment: does this produce an error?

Comment: yes, TypeError: cannot create mpf from 1.0

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert the `longdouble` to `np.float64` :

```
import numpy as np
import mpmath

b = np.longdouble(1.0)
c= np.float64(b)
a = mpmath.mpf(c)
print (a)
```